# What is the bump in the resistivity vs temperature curve of the nichrome 80 wire?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance, metals

I have measured the resistivity of a nichrome ($80$ Nickel $20$ Chrome) wire as a function of temperature.
[image]

Because my setup is quite crude (just a power supply and a couple of multimeters to measure voltage and current), I do not know if the bump that I get around $0.6A$ is physical or an artifact of the measuring setup.

However, I stumbled across this plot online (https://super-metals.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Nichrome-Alloys-for-Heating.pdf)
[image]
I can see that the same bump is present more or less at the same temperature. It is not very clear if this **temperature factor** is the temperature coefficient of resistance or what.

So my question is:

**What is the physical explanation for that bump?**

I am a particle Physicist so you can assume I understand the basics of thermodynamics and quantum mechanics.

If you happen to know the real source of the figure it would help immensely.

EDIT$1$: I have substituted the Resistance vs Current plot with the more explicative Resistivity vs Temperature plot.

EDIT$2$: I found another site online where the same behavior was observer: http://www.brysonics.com/heating-a-nichrome-wire-with-math/

Comment: The temperature coefficient of resistance has little to do with your plot. Essentially, in your case you did the experiment near ambient temperature, and Joule heat probably hasn't increase that much the resistance of your wire. The temperature coefficient of resistance you have plotted is completely flat in the region of interest.

Comment: That is definitely not the case. I have modeled the wire temperature quite accurately and the in the range of 0A to 1.3A the wire temperature varies from ambient to 1400 C. Besides that, the wire was glowing yellow at 1.2A. In any case, even if we do not consider the first plot, what is the meaning of the bump in the second plot?

Comment: Alright, I am quite confused. I preferred your resistance (instead of resistivity, which you did not measure but calculate), or voltage, vs I.  
If the temperature coefficient is worth 1/R dR/dT, the bump in R(T), or R(I) for that matter, should yield a negative temperature coefficient. But the 2nd plot has positive values in the whole range.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what they mean now, it;s a relative change in %, not the absolute temperature coefficient.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, I think it's a good one (hence my upvote). It would be interesting to see Ni and Cr's curves, too, at least to see whether this comes from either of these metals.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comments. When you say "relative change in %", I more or less see what you mean but I am having difficulties understanding precisely relative to what quantity.

Comment: In the page you linked, it is written "This variation is stated as percentage change from the actual room temperature resistance.". The graph seems to start at 0C, so the relative coefficient is worth 1 there. At 600C, the bumpy curves have increased by around 6% to 7%, this means that R has increased by that relative percentage, too. The title of the graph is misleading in my opinion, it doesn't match the text explanation, but the text seems more correct because of the value of the temperature coefficient, which shouldn't be near unity. Anyway the answer probably lies in condensed matter or s

Comment: olid state physics, electronic energy bands, possibly the Fermi surface and those kind of things. Maybe even a phase transition, etc. I don't know the answer at all, but that would be my guess.

Comment: How are you measuring the wire temperature? I'd be interested in seeing how uniform the temperature is along the sample length.

Comment: That is an interesting question. Actually, I am not measuring the temperature but calculating it numerically by integrating the heat equation of the wire. This theoretical calculation is not state-of-art but accurate enough for our purposes. 
I tried measuring the temperature with a thermocouple but the thermocouple heat capacity is much greater than the wire one, making the measurement inaccurate. I tried with an infrared thermometer but without focusing lenses or a black body enclosure is not feasible.

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform Here is the [pure Nickel resistivity vs temperature](https://aip.scitation.org/action/showOpenGraphArticleImage?doi=10.1063/1.4896046&id=images/medium/1.4896046.figures.f12.gif). I could not find something similar for Chromium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nichrome wire undergoes a phase transition at that mysterious temperature which changes its unit cell structure. The two different unit cells have slightly different bulk resistivities. Superimposed on that shift is the usual increase in resistivity with temperature for metallic solids.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that phase transition ?  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenG, a google search will bring up the Cr-Ni phase equilibrium diagram versus temperature. There's a lot of possible activity there depending on the exact percentages of the alloy constituents.

Comment: It seems that this is the correct answer. I found [this article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.634.6705&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that supports this answer. The article is from 2002 and at that time it was still not clear which kind of structural phase transition was happening.